# I can't find some types of Admin Audit Activity Events

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I checked this url below,

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-event-names

And created a script to check event for each activity type. After then, I found some activity types are Not listed on this table.

- CUSTOM_USER_SCHEMA_SETTINGS
- SAML2_SERVICE_PROVIDER_CONFIG_SETTINGS

Could you please tell me where I can get more information regarding them if you have.
Best regards,

Comment: Where did you get the names of these events if they are not listed? I am just curious if you have added "CUSTOM_USER_SCHEMA_SETTINGS" because you believe that that is what it should be listed as, or if you have found it somewhere else?

Comment: @iansedano, thank you for your comment. I' writing up a program to check admin activity so I read [this page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin) and have implemented.
By checking JSON response events-> name through this program, I could found activities that are defined such as `APPLICATION_SETTINGS`, `DELEGATED_ADMIN` or `ORG_SETTINGS` etc. That's why I found unknown event name `CUSTOM_USER_SCHEMA_SETTING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For what its worth, I can't find it either

It seems that these activity types are not supported by the API, at least I could not find any way to get those events.

In which cased I would encourage you to make a feature request using this template:

- [**Admin SDK Feature Request**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102)

That way Google at least know that there are people who would like to see this. Make sure to justify the request with your practical use case so that they understand *why* you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll put the request on the site.